# JRuby 1.7.6 cannot install gems

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm, jruby

I am using RVM and Homebrew on OS X Mavericks. JRuby 1.7.6 installs, but I cannot install any gems. I believe that JRuby comes with a semi-complete version of openssl. I have tried using http for gem sources, and even downloaded the gem for a local install. I see this same error regardless of gem locality or gem source.

```
$ jruby -S gem install bundler --trace
ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
    load error: openssl -- java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass
```

Others Rubies (1.8.7, 1.9.3, 2.0.0) are working without issue in RVM.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the ruby first:

```
rvm use jruby-1.7.6
```

It will ensure all jruby gems are available for it.

Comment: I should have mentioned that this error is issued when I am already "using" that jruby version.

Comment: how about just `gem install bundler --trace` and where is the trace?

Comment: maybe: `ruby -dS gem install bundler`

Comment: Spent some time on IRC today with the JRuby devs. They are stumped. I created a gist for them to look at. [link](https://gist.github.com/mpokress/7237524)

Comment: Later I installed JDK 7 from Oracle and tried reinstalling JRuby. Same result. I don't know if JRuby depends on a specific version of openssl on the OS or if it has an internal implementation, but I'm thinking it is an incompatibility outside of Java altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a proxy blocking your access to the gemserver?

`jruby -S gem source --add http://rubygems.org`?